# Transaction Error: Error: non-payable method cannot override value

Tags: solidity, web3js

I Designed a quiz app which simply withdraws the amount earned by user after playing the game from the smart contract.But Each time i click on the withdraw button to call the withdraw function on my smart contract i always get the above error(Transaction Error:  Error: non-payable method cannot override value ) here is the withdraw code for the frontend

````
const {ethereum} = window;
    
    if (ethereum) {
      console.log("withdrawing")
      
      const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(ethereum, "any");
      const signer = provider.getSigner();
      const contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, abi, signer);
      try {
        const tx = await contract.withdraw(userAddress, { value: earnedInWei });

        await tx.wait();
        console.log("Transaction Successful!");
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Transaction Error: ", error);
      }
    } else {
      console.error("No web3 provider found. Please install MetaMask or use another web3 provider");
    }
  }``` 



and below is my smart contract

```//SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED

pragma solidity >=0.8.7;

contract ethQuiz {

//address of the owner of the smart contract
address payable public owner;

//Making sure that only the owner calls the smart contract
constructor(){
    owner= payable(msg.sender);
       }  
//funding the smart contract
    receive() external payable {
    }
  
//for users to withdraw funds from the smart contract
function withdraw(uint256 amount) external {
    require(amount <= address(this).balance, "too much!");
    payable(msg.sender).transfer(amount);
    }

//to check the available balance in the smart contract
function getBalance() external view returns (uint){
    return address(this).balance;
    }
}
//initial amount on smart contract:300000000000000000 wei```
````

Answer (score 2):

> `const tx = await contract.withdraw(userAddress, { value: earnedInWei });`

`withdraw()` isnt a payable method, and you're trying to send ether to it.
I believe what you're trying to do is just `const tx = await contract.withdraw(earnedInWei);`

Comment: yess!!!! thanks alot you are right...everything works fine now

Answer (score 2):

withdraw is not a payable method so you can not send ether to this method.
@Foxxxey is correct

Do this

```
const tx = await contract.withdraw(earnedInWei);
await tx.wait().then(data => {
   console.log('data', data)
})
```

Comment: yes thanks alot,really appreciate